# Two laravel projects have three databases

Tags: mysql, laravel

Two laravel projects，`laravel_a` and `laravel_b`，they have their respective database `database_a` and `database_b`.

Now there is some common data,I created the third database `database_common`,
How do the two projects read the third database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a extra database connections. Try like this:

In `config/database.php`:

```
'connections' => [

    'common_db' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('COMMON_DB_HOST', ''),
        'port' => env('COMMON_DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('COMMON_DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('COMMON_DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('COMMON_DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('COMMON_DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],

],
```

In `.env`:

```
COMMON_DB_CONNECTION=mysql
COMMON_DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
COMMON_DB_PORT=3306
COMMON_DB_DATABASE=yourDatabaseName
COMMON_DB_USERNAME=yourDatabaseUsername
COMMON_DB_PASSWORD=yourDatabasePassword
```

Then you can write the query like this:

```
$users = DB::connection('common_db')->select(...);
```

---

Ref: [Database: Getting Started](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database#introduction). Read this page carefully.