# Multiple laravale websites - Central login system & Shared one database

Tags: laravel, database, authentication, single-sign-on, common-table-expression

I have multiple Laravel websites, and I wanted to have one central login system for that.
The idea workflow is:

- User wanted login to "website 1"
- by clicking to "login button" will be redirected to main "central login system" which is on different domain.
- After user login there, then will be redirected back to the "website 1"
- After user login there, will get also access to all websites, which means this:
  I will create some button with dropdown (like google has), in the dropdown will be all websites logo with links. So user can go to any site like "website1,website2 etc.." and will stay still logged (before not logout)
- for the main central login system, I have some nice Laravel script which is created exactly for my needs, it is an user management system, where can users register, login, reset pass, remember feature there, social login, etc...all main things about user management. This system wanted use as the Central Login system, so I think if I need for that idea some of "Common database", then should be used not new database, but the current "central login system database".

Anybody has idea how to this please? Really thank you for any reply, because its important for me. Without having this, cant go live with any website separately, because this is required (because have multiple websites). Sure someone know what to do.

I find this link:
[Two laravel projects have three databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50075315/two-laravel-projects-have-three-databases)

There something about that, but its not correct for me exactly, because:
1/ I am not developer, but I know basics
2/ the man who did this question, don't specified what he did inside the common database.

Best regards everyone.
Thank you REALY

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this package](https://github.com/24Slides/laravel-saml2) to enable Single Sign-on(SSO) in Laravel application